# How to use TimeDistributed Layer on keras?

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So when I was trying to train a model with LSTM, I have reshaped my input data to (1000, 96, 1), and output data to (1000, 24, 1), which means I want to predict futural 24 data with previous 96 data.
When I add a timedistributed dense layer as the last layer, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have shape (96, 1) but got array with shape (24, 1)
```

So what's wrong?
Here are my codes:

```
modelA.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True,
                input_shape=[xProTrain_3D.shape[1], xProTrain_3D.shape[2]]))
modelA.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
modelA.add(Dropout(0.25))
modelA.add(Dropout(0.25))
modelA.add(LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True))
modelA.add(Dropout(0.25))
modelA.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
modelA.add(Dropout(0.25))
modelA.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
modelA.add(Dropout(0.25))
modelA.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(24, 1))))
modelA.compile(optimizer='Adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mse']) 
modelA.summary()
modelA.fit(x=xProTrain_3D, y=yProTrain_3D, epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch_size)
```

By the way, the input shape is (1000, 96, 1) and output shape is (1000, 24, 1)

Comment: there is nothing in the network that reduces the timesteps dimension in order to pass from 96 to 24